# Expectation-Maximization in Weka for custom objects

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, expectation-maximization

I'm planning to use the Java [Weka](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) library's EM algorithm in order to assign probabilities to objects to be in a certain cluster and then, work with these probabilities.

Furthermore, the properties of those objects will be loaded from a database, so I would like to load them into the clusterer directly from memory, instead of dumping them to an arff file as in the examples I have found around the web (e.g. [Serialization](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization)).

Firstly, I would like to know if the Weka library is the proper one for my purpose of there exists another one such as Apache Commons Math.

Secondly, is there any example which does not manage any file in order to create Instances?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have to convert your objects into Instance object. If you have valid Instance objects you can employ weka for your task

Comment: I saw this one, which may help: https://ianma.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/weka-with-java-eclipse-getting-started/

Comment: Yes you can do it like this to construct your instances but why not creating an arff and read all the data in a twoliner ;)

Comment: ELKI has a rather extensible architecture. I haven't played with their EM much, but it may be easier to extend than Weka's.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Another option should be to try R with Java using JRI. For the moment, I think I will continue the Weka way...

Comment: When considering using R you should consider to create an arff. R is able to read arffs too.